# Does iOS 10 support geotags for MMS messages?

Tags: photos, messages, geolocation, android

I am finding that MMS messages are consistently not containing geotag data using iMessage. This occurs for iMessage on iOS 10.0.2 and MacOS 10.11.6. When I am within the iMessage app (either on my Mac or iPhone) and I receive a photo from an Android user or an iPhone user that has not enabled iMessage it would appear the file does not contain the geotag data. I have tried saving the photo directly to my photo library as well as saving the photo to file. (On iPhone I tried saving it to DropBox and iCloud Drive as a file.) In either case, the resultant photo/file simply has no geotag data with it. In one instance, for an Android user, I asked the person to email the same photo as an email attachment and the photo file did in fact have geotag data, so the problem seems to be isolated just to photos sent over MMS using iMessage.

Is this a known issue, bug, or limitation of iMessage? Or is there there something wonky going on with just my phone? It's highly annoying as I like to save photos carefully with location data, and it's disappointing that any photo sent to me via MMS will simply not have it.

Comment: It may be just the MMS protocol not supporting geotagging.

Comment: From what I've read, it would appear it completely depends on how the image was sent. When images get processed, like when it gets downsized, exif data is typically stripped and so does the geotag data. This seems really lazy, but I guess it's the norm.

Comment: Also, for the record, when you export photos from the Photos app on MacOS, I found that unless you explicitly choose the option that exports the file unaltered, all metadata gets stripped.